# In C checking the value of every element and return true or function

Tags: arrays, c

Can someone help me or give idea on how can I correct my logic in the array loop

My Problem is I have student quiz scores and perfect quiz scores

My Goal is I want to compare student quiz scores every element to the Perfect quiz scores, where Student scores cannot be negative value or greater than the perfect quiz scores, and if it is inputted negative I just want to reinput it to the value where it is not negative or greater than the quiz scores, but I really have no idea how to do it.

Also I tried creating function for `quizScore` and input the loop there and if the quiz is either negative or greater than, then I'll just call the `quizScore` function but it still fails.

```
void initStudents() {
    printf("\nEnter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &studentCount);
    for(int i=0; i < studentCount; i++){
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\n[Student %d of %d]\n", i + 1,studentCount);
        printf("Enter name of student %d: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%s",studentNames[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < qCount; j++){
        printf("\n[Quiz %d of %d] \n", j + 1, qCount);
        printf("Enter score for quiz %d: \n", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &quiz[j]);
        if(quiz[j] < 0 || quiz[j] > qPerfect[j]) {
            quiz[j] = 0;
        }
        else {
            //no idea what to put here
        }
    }
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(int j = 0; j < pCount; j++) {
        printf("\n[Project %d of %d]\n", j + 1, pCount);
        printf("Enter score for project %d: \n", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &project[j]);
    }
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(int j = 0; j < hmCount; j++) {
        printf("\n[Homework %d of %d]\n", j + 1, hmCount);
        printf("Enter score for homework %d: \n", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &homework[j]);
    }       
}
//end of initstudents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `while`

```
while (quiz[j] < 0 || quiz[j] > qPerfect[j]) {
    printf("Invalid score \n");
    printf("Enter score for quiz %d: \n", j + 1);
    scanf("%d", &quiz[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! now my code is good to go <3

Answer (score 2):

Loop until there's a valid input:

```
while (true) {
    printf("\n[Quiz %d of %d] \n", j+1, qCount);
    printf("Enter score for quiz %d: \n", j+1);
    scanf("%d",&quiz[j]);

    if (quiz[j] < 0 || quiz[j] > qPerfect[j]) {
        quiz[j] = 0;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! now my code is good to go <3